# Splash screen window does not load items

Tags: c#, wpf, initialization, splash-screen

I'm trying to use a window as splash screen. I have this:

```
{ 
InitializeComponent();
new splash().ShowDialog();
}
```

in my main window to start up with and it works but on the window that I'm using as splash when I press start it stays blank. This is the code I'm using for the splash window:

```
public partial class splash : Window
    {
        public splash()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Close();

        }
```

As it is it just loads the window blank and after 3secs it moves on to the main window.
I want the splash window to load with a label and an image.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Here is an excellent guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38291/Implement-Splash-Screen-with-WPF, and also worth mentioning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (If your splash is just an image) But you main problem is Thread.Sleep() as it blocks the Ui thread. Use a timer instead :)

Comment: as with @qqbenq 2nd suggestion using a simple image as a splash screen resources is the way to go IMO.

Answer (score 1):

So, as I already mentioned it in my comment, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38291/Implement-Splash-Screen-with-WPF) is an excellent guide on how to implement a splash screen for WPF applications. Also Microsoft offers an easier way if your splash screen is only an image (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

But the main problem with your code is the `Sleep(3000)` call, as it blocks the UI thread. Use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, which you can start in the window loaded event handler, and close the window in the Timer's Elapsed event handler.

Hope this helps.

(Sorry for almost duplicating my comment, but at the third edit I realized it actually should be an answer :))